# how to do post request with raw data via spring rest template

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, heap-analytics

Can some one tell me how to send a POST request with raw data parameters as in the picture below 
[image]

i have tried the following code but its not working

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            JsonObject properties = new JsonObject();
            MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();         
            try {

                properties.addProperty("app_id", appId);
                properties.addProperty("identity","TestAPI");
                properties.addProperty("event", "TestCompleted");
                properties.addProperty("testType", t.getTestType());
                properties.addProperty("testName",t.getTestName());
                properties.addProperty("chapter","");
                properties.addProperty("module","");
                properties.addProperty("pattern",t.getTestPattern());
                HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(
                        properties.toString(), headers);
               // params.add("properties", properties.toString());
                 restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);
```

can someone help?

Comment: you can use @request body if it's structure is static

Comment: @poojapatil how? can you tell me an example?

Comment: create an Dto where you will have the above fields in it, to post use webclient , such as (client.target(end url)
     .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header(if any header)

     .post(Entity.entity(scheme, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));)

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
@RestController
public class SampleController { 
    @RequestMapping("/req")
    public String performReqest(){
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);        
        JsonObject properties = new JsonObject();
        properties.addProperty("no", "123");
        properties.addProperty("name", "stackoverflow");
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(properties.toString(), headers);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:4040/student", request, String.class);
        return "Response from Server is : "+response;       
    }

    @RequestMapping("/student")
    public String consumeStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
        System.out.println(student);
        return "Hello.."+student.name;
    }   
}

class Student{
    public int no;
    public String name; 
    public Map<String,String> properties;   
}
```

Don't forgot to move `Student` class and change all field to `private` with require getters and setters.
Above code is only for demo purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this:

```
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u tried using postmaster and checked the output first. If its working then you can go for post or exchange method. exchange returns and post dont.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
URI uri = new URI("something");
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("app_id", "something");
        params.put("identity", something);

HttpEntity<Map<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity(params , headers);
   
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, String.class);
```